# Ionic Failed to load resource: The requested URL was not found on this server

Tags: ios, ionic-framework

I have the following problem, I have an application developed with Ionic 1, this application allows the user to select a background, as well as Whatsapp conversations, this works very well on the android, when selecting the image I save the image path In my localstorage, and always renderiso it as background, in ios the rescue also occurs well but when I leave the application and I return I get the following error message and the image is not loaded:

> Failed to load resource: The requested URL was not found on this
>   server.

Does anyone know how I can solve this in IOS?

Answer (score 0):

Hit this issue as well. In my case it was an interpolation issue. I had my `ng-src` without curly brackets:

```
<img ng-src="user.image">
```

When adding the appropriate syntax it worked:

```
<img ng-src="{{user.image}}">
```